# Ways to delete or isolate entire rows in a huge data collection

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I'm working with a huge datafile (about 400,000 rows and 8 columns) in Libre Office. I need to get rid of certain rows so I selected all cells with the desired value (with `Find & Replace`) and tried `Edit > Delete Cells > Delete entire row(s)`. The screen is fading and still, after some 15 minutes it doesn't get me anywhere (screen fades to grey, program does not respond). Selecting "only" some thousand rows resulted in the same.

Is there an alternate way to get rid of thousands of rows at the same time? Solutions in Libre Office, Gnumeric or R or any other open software are very welcome.

The data is organised in this way (small sample):

> Region, TimePeriod, etc, ValueTons
>
> Cyprus, JanDec 2000, somecodes, 0
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2001, somecodes, 74.2
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2002, somecodes, 68.7
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2003, somecodes, 59.1
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2004, somecodes, 50.3
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2005, somecodes, 71.1
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2006, somecodes, 45.7
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2007, somecodes, 45.7
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2008, somecodes, 50.4
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2009, somecodes, 80
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2010, somecodes, 47.2
>   Cyprus, JanDec 2011, somecodes, 44.1
>   Spain, JanDec 2000, somecodes, 5
>   ...

The time period ranges from 2000 to 2011. I need to get rid of all rows containing the years 2000 to 2005 and 2011.

Comment: what format is the file in? csv?

Comment: Forgot to add that. I can save it in .csv if that is of help. At the moment it is an .ods file.

Comment: if you have enough ram, you can easily read it into R using `read.csv` and filter from there. if you do not have enough ram, you can still use `sqldf` package to do the same

Comment: How many are the remaining rows? Maybe it would be easier to just copy the remaining rows to another file than deleting too many rows?

Comment: if you want more help, try posting a segment of your data and what you want to filter by. this makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: Added a sample of data to the question. The remaining rows are roughly the same as the rows to delete. I figured out that Libre Office is able to handle the data, it just takes a long while. Haven't looked into the R solution proposed by RJ but do not know much about R so maybe I'll just go with doing it step by step. Do you think R would handle it way faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

1.Save it as CSV.

2. Rename it to TXT (if on Windows, uncheck the checkbox to hide known extensions, on tools > options to show extensions), only to LibreOffice does not try to open it with Calc.
3. Open it with Write. To do it more clear for eyes, select Dysplay > Web Layout.
4. Select lines you want to erase and do it. From first line, put cursor before first character, then hold shift and use down arrow page up/down keys to select the lines to delete.
5. After ending the deletion of unimportant lines, save the file (as TXT) and rename it back to CSV.

Note: You will delete all formulas if exist.